# Formatting a list of doubles into a string

Tags: haskell, dictionary, printf

I am trying to format a list of doubles into a string. I would like to turn a list such as:

```
[0.38, 0.94]
```

into something like:

```
"aString 0.380  0.940"
```

I have tried:

```
"aString" ++ map (printf "%7.3f") [0.38, 0.94]
```

and get the feedback:

```
<interactive>:80:19:
    No instance for (PrintfType Char)
      arising from a use of `printf'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (PrintfType Char)
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(printf "%7.3f")'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `map (printf "%7.3f") [0.38, 0.94]'
    In the expression: "aString" ++ map (printf "%7.3f") [0.38, 0.94]
```

I've not been able to fix this. I have unable to compose a signature that works.

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that `map (printf "%7.3f") [0.38, 0.94]` is of type `[String]`, not `String`. Use `concatMap`:

```
Prelude Text.Printf> "aString" ++ concatMap (printf "%7.3f") [0.38, 0.94]
"aString  0.380  0.940"
```